# How to Call Fast API in kotlin Android Studio

Tags: android, api, kotlin, parameter-passing, getmethod

I'm working on a project where I created an API where I can get trends from twitter based on user's entered location. Now I want to call that API in android.
It looks like:
[image]

I want to show the GET Trends here:
Get Trends Layout:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        tools:context=".trends">
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profiletitle"
            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="Today's Trends"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/Twit"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="48dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="29dp" />
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/locationid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="105dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="133dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter your country"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/getdata"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="216dp"
            android:text="Get Trends" />
    
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/showtrends"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="492dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="310dp">
    
        </FrameLayout>
    
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

I need your help to tell me how to do it in kotlin. I have searched many times but failed to find the solution where I can pass my **Country parameter** from **andriod to API** and then get the **json results.** Your Answer will be highly appreciated.

My Response Body I want to display:

[image]

Comment: you can use retrofit or volley network library with recyclerview in your Framelayout.

Comment: I'm using that but I'm not able to pass parameter of location to my API Get Trends Method and Get the JSON Result based on that location parameter

Comment: which network library currently you are using? and which architecture you are using for your code?

Comment: I'm using retrofit library to call my API. What do you mean by Architecture?

Comment: Architecture pattern -like MVVM,MVC,MVP,MVI etc

Comment: I'm not using any Architecture

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244797/discussion-between-sandesh-khutalsaheb-and-ayman-amjad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try once and make JSON as per your requirement and other related changes like clear textview on each click etc... -

XML FILE

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center|top"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:text="Today's Trends"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/locationid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter your country"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/getData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="Get Trends" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/showData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
 
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Class file-

```
    public class MainActivity4 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
        Button getData;
        EditText locationId;
        TextView showData;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
            locationId = findViewById(R.id.locationid);
            showData = findViewById(R.id.showData);
            getData = findViewById(R.id.getData);
            getData.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int id = view.getId();
            if (id == R.id.getData) {
                String location = locationId.getText().toString().trim();
showData.setText("");
                if (location.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please add Country", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
    
                RequestQueue requestQueue;
                requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n") JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                        "https://twtsentiment-fastapi.herokuapp.com/get_trend?loc=" + location,
                        null, response -> {
                    Log.d("Response", response.toString());
    
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Trends");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            showData.append("\n "+jsonArray.optString(i)+"\n ");
                            Log.d("TEXT", jsonArray.optString(i));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
    
                }, error -> Log.d("myapp", "something went wrong"));
                requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please Confirm  How can I clear previous screen when I add the new Entry?

Comment: update only this code 
 showData.setText("");
            if (location.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please add Country", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            } you need to add only one line of code I have copy pasted more for your reference.

Comment: What changes do I need to do if I want to implement it in a Fragment

Comment: Giving me error : Type mismatch: inferred type is trends but View.OnClickListener? was expected.......on this line       binding?.getData!!.setOnClickListener(this)

Comment: Only add this line in in onclick listener --- showData.setText("");

Comment: @AymanAmjad code updated check once

Comment: If there are two variables in Response Body, how to get them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244813/discussion-between-sandesh-khutalsaheb-and-ayman-amjad).

Comment: I want the same thing for another parameter here https://twtsentiment-fastapi.herokuapp.com/docs#/default/twt_link_twt_link_get     but it has multiple values in Response body.